# gaelyk plugin system (use of quandl4j)

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, quandl, gaelyk

I have wondered how it would be possible to use gaelyk plugin system for quand4j which is a library on top of quandl (open data system). After many attempts of adding manually to `build.gradle` like the excerpt hereunder without any success, could someone point me at good reference for plugins in gaelyk (both gradle and plugins.groovy)?

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'gaelyk'
apply plugin: 'appengine-geb'

def compatibilityVersion = 1.7
sourceCompatibility = compatibilityVersion
targetCompatibility = compatibilityVersion

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "http://maven.opengamma.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    def gaeVersion = '1.9.4'
    def groovyVersion = '2.3.0'
    ...
    compile 'com.jimmoores:quandl:0.8.1'   
}
```

Comment: what exactly should the plugin do?

maybe https://github.com/gaelyk/gaelyk-resources-plugin is a good example of Gaelyk binary plugin

Comment: @musketyr : it is a library for open data (stats, stock price....),

Comment: the error is following:Could not find com.opengamma.external.json:json:1.0.0.v20101106.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/opengamma/external/json/json/1.0.0.v20101106/json-1.0.0.v20101106.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/opengamma/external/json/json/1.0.0.v20101106/json-1.0.0.v20101106.jar
...snip...